# Parse multiple JSON file into HTML table using PHP --too many rows

Tags: php, json, html-table

I'm running a python script which returns JSON files to a certain directory. I am then inserting the data from these files into an HTML table. Everything is working fine except that for every entry I get 3 rows, one with the information I need and the other two are blank. I think the error is in my PHP code but I can't seem to fix it. Any help would be appreciated! 
**I was able to eliminate showing the rows by making the padding on the td/tr tags 0 but I want to fix this the right way.**

```
<style>

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>IP Address</th>
       <th>Manufacturer</th>
       <th>Model</th>
       <th>BIOSFamily</th>
       <th>BIOSDate</th>
       <th>SerialNumber</th>
       <th>More Information</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$dir = "/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Reserve1";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        foreach(glob("*.json") as $filename) {
            $data = file_get_contents($filename);
            $testing = json_decode($data, true);
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$filename }</td>";
            foreach($testing as $row) {
                echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['Manufacturer']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['Model']}  </td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['BIOSFamily'] }</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['BIOSDate'] }</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['SerialNumber']}</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Move the `echo "</tr>";` outside of your `foreach($testing as $row) {}` loop because it is causing invalid HTML.

Comment: You are are also missing a `</tbody>` and a `</body>`

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to put the filename only on the first row and not in all the other rows?

Comment: Yes i am, reason being is the filename(ip address in this case) is not part of the data in the JSON file so its the only way i can get it to display.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before just move `echo "</tr>";` outside of the foreach.

```
<style>

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>IP Address</th>
       <th>Manufacturer</th>
       <th>Model</th>
       <th>BIOSFamily</th>
       <th>BIOSDate</th>
       <th>SerialNumber</th>
       <th>More Information</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $dir = "/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Reserve1";
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                foreach(glob("*.json") as $filename) {
                    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
                    $testing = json_decode($data,true);
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>{$filename }</td>";
                    foreach($testing as $row) {
                        echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['Manufacturer']}</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['Model']}  </td>";
                        echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['BIOSFamily'] }</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['BIOSDate'] }</td>";
                        echo "<td>{$row['Comments']['SerialNumber']}</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        }
?>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps, otherwise print your `$testing` with `var_dump` or `print_r` to have a look if the data is correct.

Comment: When I do that I get extra columns. All the information being inserted is correct, its just either too many rows and in the case when i put my </tr> outside my for loop I get too many columns at the end of my table. The rows are consistent but now too many columns(8 extra).